# Best video editor for joining & cutting .mpg

Tags: 12.04

What is the best video editor for joining & cutting .mpg on Precise? For example,joining .mpg files for joining first half & second half of a film, and for cutting out adverts?

Answer (score 2):

Avidemux and Open Shot. The later parallels Adobe Premiere in interface and features.